# How to use a monitor which is not part of desktop (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, monitor

I would like to use a monitor which is actually marked "disconnected" in the windows control panel under "Change display settings". (I do NOT mean a physically disconnected monitor.)

I know how to add a second monitor in Windows and make it part of desktop. I also know how to make my application run on a primary or on secondary monitor when they are part of desktop.

I have a piece of equipment attached to the PC which has a touch screen on it. The touchscreen is connected to the PC over USB looking as an ordinary USB-Monitor and I can make it part of my Windows desktop. But that is not what I want.

What I would like to do is make sure that only one special application can run on this monitor. I also do not want to have a windows desktop on it because than the user could move any window to it which is not what I want. The idea behind all this is to use the touch screen to have an application on it which can control this external piece of equipment. The user would only have to run the PC but not to login. I was thinking about starting the app from a windows service before the windows desktop is loaded. And once the user logs in I do not want him to be able to use the touch screen for anything else except this special application. That is why the touch screen must not be part of the windows desktop but ”deactivated”.

I am using . NET 4.0 and C# for my application, but I will use C++ or whatever comes handy.

Any help or idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Windows Sideshow... My Dell XPS420 has a separate screen with some controls that can run Windows Gadgets.

Comment: I think I would need a special hardware for Sideshow. (Or did I get this wrong?) What I have is this USB monitor which I would like to use as it is. And I don't mind if my PC has to be "on" if only the user does not have to log in on the main screen.

Comment: You are not going to be able to use a monitor that Windows believes is disconnected and limit its use to only your application.  Windows must be able to use it for your application to use it, and in turn, this means any application that wants to use it can use it.

Comment: Maybe, since the monitor is known in the system, there is a way to draw something on it. Maybe through DirectX or something else I might get hold of it and smuggle it in.

Comment: I did some testing using DirectX 9 and Direct 3D. Unfortunately for me it seems that DirectX does not know the monitor (“adapter” in DirectX parlance) once it is deactivated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems WDDM does not support independent displays any more. Here are a few links in case somebody wishes to take a look for himself:

1. ([old MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145071(v=vs.85).aspx)) = [/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-display-monitors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-display-monitors)
2. ([old MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145179(v=vs.85).aspx)) =  [/windows/win32/gdi/using-multiple-monitors-as-independent-displays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-multiple-monitors-as-independent-displays)

The important part is this note from the second link:

> ⓘ Note
>
> Using other monitors as independent displays isn't supported on drivers that are implemented to the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM).

Comment: Are you saying Windows 7+ only has WDDM displays, and so independent displays are impossible? The article is a bit confusing to me as it starts off saying this is possible (and Windows 7 has been out for quite some time..).