# Access to a monitor not containing the desktop

Tags: linux, windows-7, x11, multiple-monitors

On a computer with multiple monitors where the desktop is not shown on one of them, is there any way to draw on that monitor from a program?

Reasoning: I need to display a variable image full-screen on a separate monitor, without the user being able to disturb the screen with the mouse or without being able to shift windows on top of my image. Example: a computer has one monitor and one projector connected; the monitor shows a "normal" desktop and the projector shows the generated image (say, a color gradient).

The first use would be on Win7, but if a portable solution exists, an X11 solution under Linux would also be nice.

Comment: Did you figure out if this is possible in Windows? Personally I don't care how (D2D, D3D, OpenGL), but having to ask clients to extend their desktop is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @MikeVersteeg: I never completely solved the problem. The current "solution" uses `setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen)` to full-screen a window on one of the "normal" screens of the desktop. While this prevents the mouse and most other windows from being shown in front of my window, it does **not** prevent _all_ overlapping windows (e.g. notification windows).

Comment: @MikeVersteeg [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13398721/127670) says that it is **not possible** on Windows.

Comment: @ian-goldby This is actually an answer to my question: Thanks. Will flag my question as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a monitor which is not part of desktop (Windows 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359228/how-to-use-a-monitor-which-is-not-part-of-desktop-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux this is easy using xvfb, a virtual framebuffer.  The command is:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x32
```

You can run programs on the virtual screen by setting the environment variable `DISPLAY=:1`

The best part is the user doesn't even have to worry about interfering with the mouse or keyboard.  Very useful for testing.

Comment: Thank you for the Linux solution: I was actually hoping that would be a one-liner or at least comparably easy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you can also run a second X session on the extra monitor

```
Xorg :1 -config /path/to/xorg_1.conf
```

But you'd need to write a xorg_1.conf configuration file to feed in.